Use of past tense "fastened" word to describe a possible future action
I am having trouble deciding on whether it is correct to use "fasten" or "fastened" in the following sentence:
(For context, the sentence is part of an advertisment for a cabinet.)

Display case for sale.  This is brand new, never been used...
Complete with both of the keys.
This can be sat on the counter or fasten to a wall.

My instinct is that it should be:

This can be sat on the counter or fastened to a wall.

Would it be correct to use "fastened" in this way?

This can be placed on the counter or fastened to a wall. Those are passives but this question is proofreading and not allowed.

The construction here is a passive verb form.  "can be fastened"   The passive is formed with a "be" verb and a past participle.  In this particular case, you have "can+ bare infinitive", and there are two parallel verb phrases

can be sat or (can be) fastened.

The tense of the verb phrase is determined not by the past participle (which is tense-less) but the main verb.  However, the main verb is "can" which is a modal verb and doesn't inflect for future tense.  The modal verb "can" indicates potential, and in particular future potential.
As the construction is passive, you must use the past participle, even when talking about future possibilities.  So "(can be) fastened" is correct, and "(can be) fasten" is wrong.

What about all the brouhaha your fellow countrymen subjected me to: re sat and stood?

sit-sat-sat  stand-stood-stood.  These are normal "strong" verbs in English

He was sat by the bar. They were stood by the window. BrE usage. Anyway, I'd say set or placed something on a bar. Not "sit" it on the bar.

Yes there is a conveyor belt of sense that moves from passive (with a participle) to an adjective. but since the words are exactly the same there is often a syntactic ambiguity.  Eg "I was bored" can be the adjective "bored" or the past particple of "bore" in a passive construction.  There is no way to tell just from the words, And, indeed often both are understood at some level. its ambiguous for translators, but no problem for regular folks since the meanings are similar. "they were sat by the bar" is similar.

Yes, but do you say: Sit those on the bar? Put them (down) on the bar; set them on the bar; place them on the bar.

"sit those glasses on the bar" is a bit odd, sounds like a country gent being is bit flamboyant (and a bit drunk).  "put them on the bar" is plain and simple.  "set the  on the bar" perhaps,  but place them on the bar suggests care.   Actually I'd likely say something else like "take them back to the bar" There isn't a fixed expression here any could be used, I suppose.

You'll hear sit with pp. sat instead of set (to place something somewhere) in American English but usually by speakers who use quite a few non-standard constructions. Standard AmE for the transitive verb is set with pp. set:  "... can be set on the counter".   When you are being shown to a seat at a restaurant,  you're being seated.
